# Solrnet namespace not found when creating a new VS2010 console app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, console-application, solrnet

I am getting the following error:

"The type or namespace name 'SolrNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have created a new console application in VS2010 and added into program.cs the line

"using SolrNet;"

I've added the project reference to SolrNet.dll version 0.4.0.2002.

Some versions of solr require a reference to system.web but I do not want to do this and I believe this version doesn't have that as a requirement. I've used the object browser and added references to Nhibernate, Castle, Niject and all the other objects.

How can I get my console app to recognise the SolrNet dll?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=140

Comment: I saw this, it's an open issue, yet SolrNet v0.4.0.2002 does not need the reference to system.web

Comment: until that issue is closed, SolrNet will depend on System.Web. If you're interested in a client profile build, I encourage you to work on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project properties, change the Target Framework from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to simply .NET Framework 4